# Why reflexive verbs in this sentence?

Tags: gramática

In this sentence:

> *A él le parecía una cosa incomprensible, como si a un italiano no le gustase la pizza o no comiese pasta.*
>
> It seemed incomprehensible to him, like an Italian who doesn't like
> pizza or doesn't eat pasta.

Why are the verbs reflexive?  Wouldn't `gusta` and `come` work as well?

Comment: Posdata: si decís las formas subjuntivas terminadas en -ese vas a dar la sensación de ser más culto. Pero si abusás demasiado vas a volverte muy insoportable. Usalas a discreción.

Comment: @tac No sé si eso es verdad en España.

Comment: @Lambie Jaja, es una opinión personal. Honestamente, creo que lo mejor es combinar ambos sufijos, ni abusar de uno ni del otro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have mis-read the sentences. These are subjunctive forms of gustar and comer not reflexives. You can check verb forms by going to the DLE entry, for instance for [gustar](https://dle.rae.es/gustar?m=form&m=form&wq=gustar#conjugacionfIHQOq1) and clicking on the button marked conjugar.

The subjunctive is needed after *como si*.

Answer (score 2):

**gustar** in the sense of like is **always reflexive**. Always.
**Me gusta eso**, **Le gusta eso**: I like that. He/she or it likes that.  gustase or gustara is imperfect subjunctive.

And **comiese** is not reflexive. **It's imperfect subjunctive**, which has two forms that mean the same thing: comiese or comiera.

For example, the verb ser can be **fuese** or *fuera*: Si [yo] fuese rica or si [yo] fuera rica. [Please note: I am not conjugating the whole thing.]

Comment: No necesariamente. También puede usarse sin los pronombres refleivos. Si decís que ‘gustás de alguien’ es equivalente a decir que estás enamoradx de alguien. Siga participando.

Comment: No en le sentido de: le gusta la pizza, le gusta las casas, etc. En este sentido, siempre será pronominal.